# Can apps script inherit styles from site?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sites

My script pulls and outputs page content from another page on my Google Site:

```
var app = UiApp.createApplication();
var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl("blah");
app.close();
return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<h1>" + page.getTitle() + "</h1>" + page.getHtmlContent());
```

I publish this and insert it into my page as an apps script component.

How do I get it to inherit its styles from the site? Can I import them somehow? I've seen I can reference external CSS or write it inline but I just want all the site's styles to be inherited/imported.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use a STyle for your page.
you can use the properties of CSS for this.

you need to create a script " style.gs" and you use css like this :

Style.gs  :

```
var css={};

css.title = {
  width : '660px',
  paddingTop :'10px',
  margin:' -12px -11px -10px',
  background : 'white', 
};
```

You use in your code for a panel for example.

code.gss :

```
var panelTitle = app.createVerticalPanel().setStyleAttributes(css.title);
```